# Why shouldn't @import be used to import a parent theme into a child theme?

Tags: import, wp-enqueue-style

I have some experience with Wordpress but I've been away from it for awhile. I've seen many examples of using @import in the beginning of the child theme to import the parent theme.

I was surprised to read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) that the correct method is to use wp_enqueue_style inside of functions.php instead of @import to load up parent themes.

I read the explanation at the bottom of the page but didn't really understand it. Is the issue that there is a performance penalty with using @import? What would be the tangible benefit of going through and updating my themes to the proper method, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@import` is a convenient CSS shortcut for loading a particular stylesheet (often parent themes or other dependencies), but part of the reason why it's generally discouraged is due to - as you had mentioned - a small performance hit (stylesheets loaded with `@import` are not loaded in parallel).

Another reason is that by loading stylesheets with Wordpress' `wp_enqueue_style` function, you are defining your style dependencies at the server level, and can therefore define conditions as to when loading a particular stylesheet is - or is *not* - appropriate.

Here's a particular use-case scenario that highlights what I'm talking about:

You've developed a theme that employs the use of several stylesheets that each have their own color scheme:

*red.css*
*blue.css*
*green.css*
*default.css*

Each color hinges off the theme's default *style.css*, and the theme itself extends the parent theme's own *style.css*. In order to select a color scheme, you've added a theme option dropdown that allows you to choose from the various options.

By using `wp_enqueue_style`, you would not only be able to enqueue only the relevant color scheme based on the existence and value of the color option, but also define the order in which all of the various stylesheets may be loaded without relying on a browser's own interpretation of the `@import` order.

Here's some [further reading](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the parallel loading issue, your explanation and the link makes it very clear.

Comment: Great information found here!

Comment: You should add this info in the codex. Seems my explanation in the codex is a bit lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Because in a standard format of wordpress, it is used to include stylesheet.css.
Though stylesheet can be included through  but we dont do it since wordpress defines its some own standard format.